# Qt - invalid use of incomplete type 'class QScrollBar' - Add horizontal scroll bar to text edit widget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qplaintextedit

The default `QPlainTextEdit` has only vertical scroll bar, I want to add horizontal scroll bar.

I tried this (this code in the constructor of the `QMainWindow` class)

```
QPlainTextEdit * editor = new QPlainTextEdit(this);
QScrollBar * hScroll = new QScrollBar(Qt::Horizontal);
editor->addScrollBarWidget(hScroll);
setCentralWidget(editor);
```

but the build failed with the error (invalid use of incomplete type 'class QScrollBar').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add horizontal scroll bar in the `QPlainTextEdit` Widget by setting the line wrap property, your code should be:

```
QPlainTextEdit * editor = new QPlainTextEdit(this);
editor->setLineWrapMode(QPlainTextEdit::NoWrap);
setCentralWidget(editor);
```

`QPlainTextEdit::NoWrap` mode will automatically add the horizontal scroll bar when the line width exceed the editor width.

Comment: but the horizontal bar is not visible until a long line is written. is there a way to make the scroller activated be default?
thanks

Comment: Why do you need a scroll bar if there are no long lines in the editor?
Both vertical and horizontal scroll bars appear only when the content exceed the editor dimensions.